# Exibir foto no ToolbarItem Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms, image

Preciso exibir a foto do lado direito do menu com o `ToolbarItem`.

Eu retorno a foto do banco de dados para a propriedade "Foto" do tipo `string`.

Converto a string foto para `Base64` e atribuo para o componente `Image` do `Xamarin Forms`.

Em outra `View`, este processo funciona perfeitamente, porém agora preciso exibi-lá na ToolbarItem.

Como posso fazer isto ?

Meu código:

\\ `XAML`

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Name="Menu2" Order="Primary" Priority="1">
      <ToolbarItem.Icon>
      </ToolbarItem.Icon>
    </ToolbarItem>
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

\\ `.CS`

```
byte[] imageBytes;
var FileImage = new Image();
imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Foto);
FileImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
```

Preciso exibir a foto aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o problema com o seu código atual?

Comment: @Genos Então, até a parte do FileImage não tem nenhum problema. Não sei como posso atribuir esse FileImage pro icone da ToolbarItem

Answer (score 1):

A propriedade `Icon` recebe um `ImageSource`.

```
this.ToolbarItems.Add (new ToolbarItem () { Icon = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageBytes))});
```